# How do I preform IO in a Yesod Form? AKA, what is the equivalent of aformM in Yesod 1.2?

Tags: yesod

I am trying to learn Yesod 1.2 and I can't figure out how to access IO and information stored in the YesodAuth instance.

For example, I can't figure out how to call getCurrentTime in Yesod 1.2.  In Yesod 1.1 you could get the current time inside a form by calling "aformM (liftIO getCurrentTime)"

Similarly, with Yesod 1.2 I can't figure out how to call "requireAuthId".

With Yesod 1.1, you get could these  two bits of data with the two lines of code starting with <*> aformM in this snippet:

```
commentForm :: EntryId -> Form Comment
commentForm entryId = renderDivs $ Comment
    <$> pure entryId
    <*> aformM (liftIO getCurrentTime)
    <*> aformM requireAuthId
    <*> areq textField (fieldSettingsLabel MsgCommentName) Nothing
    <*> areq textareaField (fieldSettingsLabel MsgCommentText) Nothing
```

I have currently resorted to querying these in the code that calls "commentForm", but this seems silly as now I have to obtain the time and user's ID multiple times.

```
commentForm :: UTCTime -> UserId -> EntryId -> Form Comment
commentForm theTime userId entryId = renderDivs $ Comment
    <$> pure entryId
    <*> pure theTime
    <*> pure userId
    <*> areq textField (fieldSettingsLabel MsgCommentName) Nothing
    <*> areq textareaField (fieldSettingsLabel MsgCommentText) Nothing
```

Help!  I've been over the docs a bunch of times and I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny, I updated the blog example just a few hours ago to include this right way to do it, together with an explanation of why it's necessary. Short version:

```
lift (liftIO getCurrentTime)
```

Comment: AH, I just use "lift requireAuthId" for the auth id. I thought I'd tried that, but I guess I must not have.

Comment: Thank you for Yesod, the book and all your help on various forums and mailing groups. You and the others working with you have really impressed me.

Comment: My pleasure, I'm glad you're enjoying yesod!